# How to detect if an element in a completed group algebra is a unit?

Tags: nt.number-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

Completed group algebras appear in Iwasawa theory and in many situations you want to know if an element is a unit. For example consider $K_n=\mathbb{Q}(\mu_{p^n})$ and $G=\varprojlim \mathrm{Gal}(K_n/\mathbb{Q})$.

Consider $g$ a primitive root of unity mod $p^2$: a natural number that generate $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$. Also consider $\sigma_g$ be the image of $g$ via the natural isomorphism between $\mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$ and $G$. I want to know if $g-\sigma_g$ or $1-\sigma_g$ is a unit in $Z_p[[G]]$. Here is my effort:

Write $G=\Delta\times\Gamma$ where $\Delta=(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\ast,\Gamma=1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$ we have $$\mathbb{Z}_p[[G]]=\mathbb{Z}_p[\Delta][[\Gamma]]\cong \mathbb{Z}_p[\Delta][[T-1]].$$
Now if we write $\sigma_g=\sigma\times\gamma$ then $\gamma$ is a topological generator of $\Gamma$, so as an element of $\mathbb{Z}_p[\Delta][[T-1]]$, $1-\sigma_g$ is $1-\sigma.(T-1)$, which is a unit because if you consider $\mathbb{Z}_p[\Delta]$ as $\mathbb{Z}_p[\mu_{p-1}]$ then $1-u_{p-1}$ is a unit but $g-\sigma_g$ isn't a unit because $g-\mu_{p-1}$ isn't a unit.

I doubted the last steps on my effort and I want to know if there are better ways to think about this problem.

Comment: Could you say what is $C$?

Comment: There is a natural ring homomorphism $\theta\colon \mathbb{Z}_p[[G]]\to \mathbb{Z}_p$. Since ring homomorphisms send units to units it might help to consider the image of your elements under $\theta$.